# Mac OS updates always restart without updating

Tags: software-update

I download the latest update and click the restart alert to finish installation. After restart, nothing has been installed and I'm asked to download the OS update all over again.

I've repeated this half a dozen times and can't get the updates to install. What's blocking this update process from actually taking place?

Comment: Sound weird, but do you have enough free space on your Mac to get the proper update?

Comment: Have 2 TB left of free space.

Comment: Might be a permissions issue because other app updates don't work either.